# How to handle an array in a SQL field?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a feed that comes from the State of Florida in a CSV that I need to load daily into MySQL.  It is a listing of all homes for sale in my area.  One field has a list of codes, separated by commas.  Here's one such sample:

```
C02,C11,U01,U02,D02,D32,D45,D67
```

These codes all mean something (pool, fenced in area, etc) and I have the meanings in a separate table.  My question is, how should I handle loading these?  Should I put them in their own field as they are in the CSV?  Should I create a separate table that holds them?

If I do leave them as they are in a field (called feature_codes), how could I get the descriptions out of a table that has the descriptions?  That table is simply feature_code, feature_code_description.  I don't know how to break them apart in my first query to do the join to bring the description in.

Thank you

Comment: Read about [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, csv data should never stored in a field, especially if you actually need to consider individual bits of the csv data, instead of just the csv string as a whole.

You SHOULD normalize the design and split each of those sub "fields" into their own table.

That being said, MySQL does have [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which allows you sort-of search those csv strings and treat each as its own distinct datum. It's not particularly efficient to use this, but it does put a bandaid on the design.

Comment: I don't always agree with this.  There is a normal form that goes to far as to render the design more inefficient.

In the case where each row might have several values that are unknown, how would one even create columns for them?

That said, (Chris), in this case Marc is dead on.  It seems that if your feature_codes are set (pool, fenced, etc) then you should create columsn/fields for each of them.

Comment: @d2burke: doesn't matter if they're unknown, a simple child table of `(parentID, name, value)` would do the trick. Then you're not stuck doing string search operations on a field. In this case, the design Scott Presnell down below has would be ideal.

Comment: The problem is, the state could add or remove any of those fields at any time.  What I was thinking was more along the lines of what Marc said with a completely separate table that holds the feature codes for each property.

Comment: You're all right in this instance, I just wanted to point out that in some cases, as in the case where you have a set of settings like WordPress meta settings that don't need to be sorted on, it's manageable to serialize the data and store it in a field, rather than creating another table or endless columns.

sorry, to muck the convo up.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the information about feature codes in a separate table, where each row is a pair of house identifier, and feature identifier

```
HouseID    FeatureID
1          C07
1          D67
2          D02
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode() to separate your CSV string : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$string = 'C02,C11,U01,U02,D02,D32,D45,D67';
$array  = explode(',', $string);
```

Then with your list of feature_codes you can easily retrieve your feature_code_description but you need to do another query to get an array with all your feature_codes and feature_code_description.

Or split your field and put it in another table with the home_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in your DB as is and when you read it out you can run the php function explode. Go check that function out. It will build an array for you out of a string separating the values by whatever you want . In your case you can use:

```
$array_of_codes = explode(",", $db_return_string);
```

This will make an array out of each code separating them by the commas between them. Good luck.